# Bootstrap 4: Vertical align floated element in a list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can I float a fontawesome icon to the right and still have it vertically middle aligned? I've tried using ml-auto and Flexbox, but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="list-group flex-column">
  <li class="list-group-item py-2 d-flex justify-content-start">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/40x40" height="40" class="mr-4">
      <span>Text Here</span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-auto" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Tell me a good reason to use float instead of flex in this case.

Comment: What do you mean vertically middle aligned? I tried your code and it is in vertically aligned with the text "Text Here"

Comment: @GerardReches I'm assuming op is mistaken and doesn't realize bs4 uses flex by default. I think they just mean align the image to the right, and center aligned vertically. they have flex classes on the `li`

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was confusing. I'm trying to have that image on the left side, text beside it and the fontawesome icon floated right. But when I float it right it's not aligned with the rest of the elements, but instead sticks to the top. How can fix this?

Comment: Your icon does seem to be on the right and centered: https://www.bootply.com/diOOJuE2qF - it is on the right of the link, if you mean completely to the right of the li, then you need to make the link stretch 100%: https://www.bootply.com/yCUtkCxiNw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the flex and sizing helper classes to make the link a `flex` parent with 2 children - the content you want on the left, and the content on the right. Use `.justify-content-between, .align-items-center` to separate the content so the arrow is on the right and centered vertically.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group flex-column">
  <li class="list-group-item py-2 d-flex">
    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <span>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/40x40" height="40" class="mr-4">
      <span>Text Here</span>
      </span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-auto" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: THANK YOU, Michael!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this structure:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center py-2" href="#">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/40x40" height="40" class="mr-4">
      <span>Text Here</span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-auto" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/p5h1r0xh/) to see it working in jsfiddle.

Your `<a>` tag doesn't fill the entire parent, so you can't see the effect of `ml-auto` on the icon. Also `d-flex` must be in the `a` tag, not in `li`.